# How can I add two different events for any JButton

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jbutton

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

    public class Proyecto_Frame extends JFrame {
    private ImageIcon Aston;
    private ImageIcon Ferrari;
    private ImageIcon Lambo;
    private ImageIcon McLaren;
/**
 * 
 */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



        public Proyecto_Frame () {
            super ("Carrera");
            this.setLayout(null);

            Aston = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("Aston1.png"));
            Ferrari = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("Ferrari1.png"));
            Lambo = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("Lambo1.png"));
            McLaren = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("McLaren1.png"));

            final JLabel Aston1 = new JLabel(Aston);
            final JLabel Ferrari1 = new JLabel(Ferrari);
            final JLabel Lambo1 = new JLabel(Lambo);
            final JLabel McLaren1 = new JLabel(McLaren);

            final JLabel Aston2 = new JLabel(Aston);
            final JLabel Ferrari2 = new JLabel(Ferrari);
            final JLabel Lambo2 = new JLabel(Lambo);
            final JLabel McLaren2 = new JLabel(McLaren);

            JButton B_Aston = new JButton (Aston);
            JButton B_Ferrari = new JButton (Ferrari);
            JButton B_Lambo = new JButton (Lambo);
            JButton B_McLaren = new JButton (McLaren);

            B_Aston.setBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(30,30,230,75));
            this.getContentPane().add(B_Aston);

            B_Ferrari.setBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(270,30,230,75));
            this.getContentPane().add(B_Ferrari);

            B_Lambo.setBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(30,110,230,75));
            this.getContentPane().add(B_Lambo);

            B_McLaren.setBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(270,110,230,75));
            this.getContentPane().add(B_McLaren);

            add(B_Aston);
            add(B_Ferrari);
            add(B_Lambo);
            add(B_McLaren);

            Aston1.setBounds(30, 250, 230, 75);
            Aston1.setVisible(false);
            Ferrari1.setBounds(30, 250, 230, 75);
            Ferrari1.setVisible(false);
            Lambo1.setBounds(30, 250, 230, 75);
            Lambo1.setVisible(false);
            McLaren1.setBounds(30, 250, 230, 75);
            McLaren1.setVisible(false);

            Aston2.setBounds(30, 350, 230, 75);
            Aston2.setVisible(false);
            Ferrari2.setBounds(30, 350, 230, 75);
            Ferrari2.setVisible(false);
            Lambo2.setBounds(30, 350, 230, 75);
            Lambo2.setVisible(false);
            McLaren2.setBounds(30, 350, 230, 75);
            McLaren2.setVisible(false);

            add(Aston1);
            add(Ferrari1);
            add(Lambo1);
            add(McLaren1);

            add(Aston2);
            add(Ferrari2);
            add(Lambo2);
            add(McLaren2);

            B_Aston.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    Aston1.setVisible(true);
                    Ferrari1.setVisible(false);
                    Lambo1.setVisible(false);
                    McLaren1.setVisible(false);
                }
            });
            B_Ferrari.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            Aston1.setVisible(false);
            Ferrari1.setVisible(true);
            Lambo1.setVisible(false);
            McLaren1.setVisible(false);
            }
            });
            B_Lambo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    Aston1.setVisible(false);
                    Ferrari1.setVisible(false);
                    Lambo1.setVisible(true);
                    McLaren1.setVisible(false);
                }
            });
            B_McLaren.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    Aston1.setVisible(false);
                    Ferrari1.setVisible(false);
                    Lambo1.setVisible(false);
                    McLaren1.setVisible(true);

                }

            });

        }

    }
```

Hey I am new to Java and got this code. So, the question here is, I want to make a selection of two of these images and paint them below the buttons in order to simulate a race. When I click any Jbutton, that image is visible and the other 3 are not, but I can not figure out how to leave that choice and make the next choice with those same JButtons. Can anyone help me? I´ve read many of the threads and many other pages but seem not to find the answer.

Thanks, and sorry for the format, not used to forums formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would tend to use a [`JList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) with a disabled `JButton` <kbd>Start Race</kbd> below it, for this.

Put the images into the list and add a [list selection listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#addListSelectionListener%28javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener%29) to detect selections.  When the selection changes, check the list for the [selected values array (1.6)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValues%28%29) or [selected values list (1.7+)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValuesList%28%29) and count the entries.

1. If the number equals 1, encourage the user to pick another (using a message `JLabel` in the main GUI, a pop-up window or a `JOptionPane`).
2. If the number equals 2, enable the button.
3. If 3 or more are selected, disable the button and show a `JOptionPane` based error message to the effect "This track is not big enough for 3 cars!".

Comment: The problem is that I just been working with Java for most 1 week now and do not understand many things on the java language, so I am trying to make it as simple as posible, although it means to have a very extense code, as you may see I have already; though I will look further into implementing this method, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is checking that if the first selection has already been made then make the second one, for example

```
if (playerA == null) {
    playerA = buttonSelection;
} else {
    playerB = buttonSelection;
}
```

Also you'd need some way to instructing the user what is selecting with what button.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution (one that I don't particularly like) is to use a boolean or other variable(s) to hold your program state, say called boolean autoSelected = false;. When the auto has been selected, change this variable to true. In the JButton's ActionListener, use an if block to determine what the code should do based on the state of this variable. In other words, you change the action that your JButtons perform depending on the *state* of the program.

Better though in my mind is to simply swap JPanels using a CardLayout and display a JPanel that holds your track and new JButtons. This is because you're changing from one major state of your program -- setting the game up, to another state -- showing the race, and these will likely need to be displayed in completely different JPanels.